# Mapping enum in typescript

Tags: typescript

What is the proper way to map enum in typescript?

For instance I am playing around with an online typescript code editor and this works fine:

```
class Message
{
    name: string;
    min: number;
    max: number;
    messageType: MessageType;
}

enum MessageType
{
    none,
    email,
    sms

}

var jsonObj = {
    "name": "some name",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 10,
    "messageType": MessageType.email

}

var messageInstance: Message = <Message>jsonObj;

console.log(messageInstance);
```

However, in my IDE `MessageType.email`shows an error of "value expected" if I use it in a json file.

If I try:

```
"messageType": "MessageType.email"
```

In the online code editor then that generates an error.

I am just getting started and can't find any clear instructions on how this should be done.

edit:

I just realised enums are number based so `"messageType": 2` or whatever corresponding number would be the correct way to go.

Is there any way to make the enum readable in the json file (i.e. something like MessageType.email as a value) as when viewed alone the json file doesn't have the enum definitions so might be confusing so I'd rather do it that way if possible..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For TypeScript 2.4+:**

You can use string enums instead of a numeric enum:

```
enum MessageType
{
    none = "none",
    email = "email",
    sms = "sms"
}
```

**For older versions of TypeScript:**

You can convert an `enum` value to a `string` using the `enum`'s indexer:

```
const messageTypeAsString = MessageType[MessageType.email];
```

Going the other way works too:

```
const messageType: MessageType = MessageType[messageTypeAsString];
```

As far as I know there is no way to automate this conversion when serializing/deserializing JSON.

The other option is to skip `enum` entirely and use static `string`s instead:

```
class MessageType {
    static readonly none = 'none';
    static readonly email = 'email';
    static readonly sms = 'sms';
}
type MessageTypeValue = 'none' | 'email' | 'sms'; 

const messageType: MessageTypeValue = MessageType.none;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am not familiar with this syntax: `type MessageTypeValue = 'none' | 'email' | 'sms'; `  What is this called?

Comment: It's a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases). It creates a type called `MessageTypeValue` which is equivalent to the union type `'none' | 'email' | 'sms'`.